# Password hash in PHP: Am I Doing This Right?

Tags: php, mysql, function, hash, passwords

I'm trying to create a login system using PHP, and I'm not quite sure if my script is really good, check out bellow.

So, I created two functions... One of them to create the hash and another one to check it out.

Check out the functions:

```
function createSaltedPass($pass = false, $username = false) {
  if($pass && $username)
  {
    $salt = hash('sha256', uniqid( mt_rand(), true ) . md5(date('d m Y H i s') . " # ") . $username);

    $pass = hash('sha256', $salt . $pass . $salt);

    $pass = $salt . $pass;

    return $pass;
  }
}
```

The snippet above creates a huge hash (to be specific 128 characters), and I don't know if it's really secure.

The first half is the salt, and it makes me able to check it out when it's needed.

The second half is the real salted password.

See an example of the password:

939cf87873a402d48bcf66a57b64ca38d6f1db9155381ffe1aae9a469e93d1e7ec338071f2dd21a96ef5fc799a3f3921b0df3188458b17422db79271056a1fda

Look at the function to check the password after using the first function:

```
function checkSaltedPass($dbPass = false, $pass = false) {
  if($pass && $dbPass)
  {
    $salt = substr($dbPass, 0, 64);

    $pass = hash('sha256', $salt . $pass . $salt);

    $pass = $salt . $pass;

    return $pass;
  }
}
```

What do you think about it? I'm not an expert in security, and I'd be greatful if someone could give me a hint.

Just one more thing: What's the better way to handle session to keep the users logged in?

(sorry about the bad english, it's not my native language).

Comment: Why are you hashing the salt twice?  Also, `checkSaltedPass` never checks whether the (hashed) passwords match!

Comment: Well, the first part creates the hash of the salt, the second do the same, but uses the salt with the password together, the third part concat. the salt and the password (that's why I was saying that the first 64 characters of the password [hashed] will be the salt). So, I can check it out in the future.

Comment: There's no need to hash salt+pass+salt; just hash salt+pass.  Using the salt a second time adds no cryptographic value.  It's also unnecessary to make the hash truly random, as long as it's different for each password.

Comment: BTW, +1 for using standard algorithms and techniques, and for double-checking _before_ you implement them, rather than after the system has been compromised.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `hash()` function , you should use [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). Its better suited for hashing passwords. And also it lets you to store salt and hash together.

As for keeping user logged in, session ends when you close your tab/browser. If you want to to let your user to be logged in for longer extent of time, you will have to use cookies.

I would recommend to use "protected" cookie for it:

> data | timestamp | verification hash

The verification hash gets created from `data + timestamp + some predefined string`. This lets you ensure that user has not messed with `data` part. Also, i would caution against use of IP for this. While that would add additional protection, it also would make the use of mobile devices (that includes laptops too) somewhat annoying.

Comment: I was just checking the crypt here... But, in that case I wouldn't be able to use the same function... At least I think so (I didn't really  test it so much to be sure)

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's a bit obvious that the password is concateneted with two sha1 hashed strings and it's easier for attacker to brute force it, by checking both hashes and the salt is a bit pointless here becouse look at your code: What are You doing is just ... not checking it at all!

In my opinion You could have a static security salt concatenated later with static user's information, like register date, registration IP (etc).

Then the usage would look smth like this:

```
$pass = sha1($password . $staticSalt . $registerDate);
```

The adventage of this is that if even the attacker would find collision with brute force then after putting found string into the `password` field, password would evaluate to :

```
$bruteForcedPassword . $staticSalt . $registerDate
```

Which would be still different then user's hashed password.

In this approche attacker have to know your static security salt, the method how You are building the password string and the user's register date (or other stuff combined into the password).

Also read about [`timing attacks`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)

Edit:
Or just use this [library for password hashing](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Comment: But if the hacker steal get your database, which I think a little bit difficult (but who know), he'll be able to find all information he needs to form a password after using the brute force method.

Comment: Look at the static security salt which is hard-coded. And even if he gets your database he has information, but how would he know how You are creating the hash ? which information You've used ? he would need a code for this, and if gets the code - nothing would save you :P

Answer (score 1):

I think the function is quite redundant
uniqid is already based on the current time.

```
function createSaltedPass($pass) {
    $salt = hash('sha256', uniqid( mt_rand(), true ));
    $pass = hash('sha256', $salt . $pass);
    return $salt . $pass;
}
```

looks enough to me

However, all that hashing stuff doesn't matter too much.
Thing that really matters is **password strength.**
For the weak passwords hashing is useless.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it as well. I'll change it.